# Div height according to content

Tags: css, height, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am working on a Modal with fixed header and footer.

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27chr463/) example

Currently the `scrollable-stuff` class height is 80%. If the content is less and there is no scrolling then i need to reduce the height and take the height of the content.

For example [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfm2sk0x/) has a less content and there is no scroller but there is a empty space. I need to take the height of the content in case if there is no scrolling.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `height: 300px;`

you can use `max-height: 300px;`

Because max-height tells the browser that the height can be less if the content is less but not greater than the specified height which in your case is `300px`.

Comment: I tried max-height:300px but the stickiness will not work then.

Comment: stickiness of what? the title?

Comment: title and buttons

Comment: if i change height to max-height , then stickiness will not work

Comment: what exactly your question os about?

Comment: 1. making text and button sticky

Comment: 2. automatically adjusting height of the modal when the content is less then the given height

Answer (score 1):

In these cases I love to take advantage of the flexbox column direction. The idea here is to have fixed heights for the footer and the header and then make the content take the rest with **flex-basis: 100%** and **flex-grow: 1**.

First of all remove the inline styling **style="width:600px;height:300px** as it is conflicting with this solution, then add a class to your modal. For the example below I chose **"myModal"**, and as a side note, use **overflow: auto**, to avoid scrollbars where there isn't enough content. This solution is also handling the default styling that comes with fancybox.

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#ModalPopup").fancybox({}).trigger('click');

});
```

```css
.title-div {
  min-height: 32px;
}

.scrollable-stuff {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.button-div {
  min-height: 32px;
}

.myModal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<div id="ModalPopup" class="myModal">

  <div class="title-div">Title</div>

  <div class="scrollable-stuff">

    <h1>For Your Information</h1>
   
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p> 
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p> 
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p> 
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
    <p>Here is some text to fill out this space.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="button-div">
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the modal height is governed by this inline style:

`<div id="ModalPopup" style="width:600px;height:300px;">`

This fixed height is what's causing the lack of responsiveness on the height of your modal. To fix this, strip out the `height:300px;`, though you may also need to find out where it's being set and change it there. A similar solution may work for the fixed width as well.

It also looks like there is a y-scrollbar, you've just got to x-scroll to get there :)

Comment: I tried that but If i remove the height:300px and if the content is alot then Header and Footer which is sticky at the moment will loose its stickiness

Comment: I tried max-height:300px but the stickiness will not work then.

Comment: Perhaps you should include this sticky functionality in your demo since it appears to be relevant to your issue :)